# Options rather than O or null in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

In my program if i doesn't select a drop down list they are storing as 0 or null values in table but they are not visible in view.Can any of u suggest me other option rather than 0 or null in database.

Comment: What else would you want to use?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more specifics? Is the problem that NULL isn't represented in your view?

Comment: use `left join` in the view instead of `inner join`?

Comment: How are you "displaying" it now and what do you want to see when nothing was selected? Please edit your question to add some details.

Comment: No,actually what i want to know is "is there any other way to pass the value rather than 0 or null when no drop down list is selected to database"?

Comment: you can use something like NA. But that is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enter some default values in your specific column that can be done in several ways

1. on insert statement if dropdown value is not selected you can pass some default values like dash (-)
2. for specific table where you need default value you can set default value using query
   ex:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE UserDetails ADD CONSTRAINT DF_SomeName DEFAULT N'-' FOR Email_ID;
   ```

hope this will help